# FOSUserBundle access_control lets users acces denied pages

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I've been using FOSUserBundle for a long time now, but this never happened to me. It seems that the firewall is not working, because I can access any page from my site, when I should only be redirected to the login page when accessing as `ANONYMOUS`.

So, this is my security file:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js|assets)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:
          invalidate_session: false
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

And this is my config.yml file:

```
 #v1.0
 imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

 fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: My\Bundle\Entity\User
```

So, from where I see, everything is configured correctly so It should work as expected. But, this is not happening. So, the questions is: where else should I look for any conflictive configuration file, or conflictive entities, etc? Because I've been debugging for hours before coming to ask the question here (I did not want to ask a silly question), but I cannot figure out what could be happening.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**your problem:**

The correct ACL attribute is `roles` not `role`.

**working examples:**

```
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        # ...
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TRANSLATOR] }
```

**explanation:**

Because of the wrong attribute name there are effectively no mandatory roles configured.

That's why - as you have `anonymous` set to `true` - access will currently be granted without any restrictions.

Please have a look at the documentation chapter [Securing specific URL patterns](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-specific-url-patterns).

Comment: but the [official documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for FOSUserBundle use role, that's why I've used it that way.

Comment: despite that little difference in the code, still using `- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }` is not working, and I can access all pages, which I shouldn't. Any idea? :S